# How to add a "subscribe to newsletter" checkbox to existing form?

Tags: html, mailchimp

I've got a basic contact form that asks for email address and a message, which is then emailed to me.  I want to add a checkbox after the email input that gives the option to subscribe to a newsletter as well.  I can do the form, I can do a newsletter sign up, I'm just not sure how to combine the two.  Any ideas?

Edit:  To clarify, I'm planning to use a basic html form.  I was hoping there'd be someway to combine that with a mailchimp or phplist newsletter signup.

Comment: You need to post up the code from the form to get any meaningful help

Comment: I would other suggest combining the email input with the checkbox input

Comment: I have this same issue, did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need an onSubmit() action with a method - generally post, and you'll probably have to use PHP and link it to that page so it knows to go there to process the action =}

in that page is where the clever stuff will happen like subscribe the user.
(Connect to the DB, add the email address to said table/column etc...)

Unfortunately this is not something I can just give you a snippet to insert - it'll have to be completed your side.